# How to force the pixel density pixel?

Tags: 14.04, laptop, screen

i want to know (and if it's possible) how to change or force the density pixel of my screen? i don't know how to do it, anyone can tell me?

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/Desktop/14.04/Unity7HighDPI

Comment: Is not what I'm looking for, but thanks for share it.